# python json.loads / json.load truncates nested json objects?

Tags: python, json

given the following code:

```
import json 
foo = '{"root":"cfb-score","children":{"gamecode":{"attribute":"global-id"},"gamestate":{"attribute":"status-id","attribute":"status","attribute":"quarter","attribute":"minutes","attribute":"seconds","attribute":"team-possession-id","attribute":"yards-from-goal","attribute":"down","attribute":"distance","attribute":"segment-number","attribute":"active-state"},"gametype":{"attribute":"type","attribute":"detail"},"stadium":{"attribute":"name","attribute":"city","attribute":"state"},"visiting-team:team-name":{"attribute":"alias"},"visiting-team:team-code":{"attribute":"global-id"},"visiting-team:team-rank":{"attribute":"rank"}}}'

bar = json.loads(foo)
print json.dumps(bar)
```

all the lowest level 'children' are truncated (or maybe more likely overwritten) except the last when using json.loads or json.load.  Why?  the json is well formed and can be validated here: http://json.parser.online.fr/

a chunk of the input:

```
"children" : {
        "gamecode" : {
            "attribute" :  "global-id"
        },
        "gamestate" : {
            "attribute" : "status-id", 
            "attribute" : "status", 
            "attribute" : "quarter", 
            "attribute" : "minutes", 
            "attribute" : "seconds", 
            "attribute" : "team-possession-id", 
            "attribute" : "yards-from-goal", 
            "attribute" : "down", 
            "attribute" : "distance", 
            "attribute" : "segment-number", 
            "attribute" : "active-state" 
        },
```

turns to this chunk of output:

```
"children" : {
            "gamecode" : {
                "attribute" :  "global-id"
            },
            "gamestate" : {
                "attribute" : "active-state" 
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is well-formed (i.e., syntactically valid) but semantically invalid.  You can't have multiple keys with the same value in a Python dict, nor in a JS object.  If you validate that input at the page you linked to, you'll see that the "JS eval" pane also shows the "truncated" data.

If you want multiple values, change the format of your data to have one key with an array value:

```
"gamestate" : {
            "attributes": ["status-id", "status", "quarter", ...]
        },
```

(Or, depending on what the overall data is like, you could just have the `gamestate` key directly link to an array instead of having another layer of nesting under the `attribute` key.)

Comment: actually, i can't do that.  the 'attribute' value is metadata i need.  i just need to switch the keys and the values so "attribute" : "status-id" will become "status-id" : "attribute".  the fact that all are attribute is by chance.  it's basically an enum of possible values

Comment: It is actually valid, but unusable in almost any language. ["The names within an object SHOULD be unique." §2.2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

Answer (score 1):

JSON doesn't care about the keys for objects, but the json.load and json.loads convert to a Python object using [this conversion table](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json-to-py-table).  JSON objects are turned into python dict's, which means you can't have repeated keys.