# JSON file gets truncated upon loading into python program

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to load a json file in to my python program

````
with open(filename,'r') as jf:
   datastore = json.load(jf)
print(datastore)```
But this trims about 10% of the JSON file
````

Comment: I think that would work... maybe it's rearranging the keys and you're not noticing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `simplejson.load(infile)` and see if there's any difference.

How large is the file?

Open it in firefox and see if everything is displayed.

Also maybe try changing encoding to utf8.

Comment: the file size is 6MB, yes everything is displayed as it should be when I open the file in firefox or any other browser/ editor

Comment: Strange.. Did you try simplejson? Also it might be the way python converts JSON to native objects. See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581875/python-json-loads-json-load-truncates-nested-json-objects